# How to generate code snippet from Postman "Get New ACCESS TOKEN" call

Tags: c#, token, postman, restsharp

I can generate code snippets from POSTMAN Get and POST CALL
I followed the steps [in this Link](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/generate_code_snippets/).

Now, I want to do the same from the "GET NEW ACCESS TOKEN CALL".(see picture below)

Actually , there is no "Code" button similar to this one
[image]

with the "Request Token" button (see below)

I tried by putting the parameters in the Body of the call, but I am always getting 401 answer

[image]

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and compare the postman and c# request.  Make the c# request look exactly like the postman request.

Comment: Just open the console before you initiate your request and copy what the request looks like onto your c# code

Comment: I tried with opening the console before calling "get new token" but it does not display clientid and secret